# Start a Service to get data from server after specified time Interval

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have a requirement to get data from server by sending a call after specified interval like 5 minutes. So app would keep checking for new data after 5 minutes. It is just like gmail or facebook. Which automatically get new feeds or emails after some time and show in list. I am using service for this like following:

```
public class MessagesLoaderService extends Service {

// constant
// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;


//********************************************************************************************************************************/

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

//********************************************************************************************************************************/

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if already existed
    if (mTimer != null) 
    {
        mTimer.cancel();
    } 
    else 
    {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MessageLoaderTask(), 0, Commons.TIME_INTERVAL_REFRESH_MESSAGES);
}

//********************************************************************************************************************************/

class MessageLoaderTask extends TimerTask 
{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Get Data from Server and store in local db
            }

        });
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Utils.showToast_msg(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroyed"); 
}



//********************************************************************************************************************************/

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Starting service from main activity MainActivity:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MessagesLoaderService.class));
```

I want service to run (send calls after 5 minutes) only when the app is running or in foreground/background. But the problem is that it keeps running even if I exit from the application. I want service to stop when Application is closed. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you stop your timer in "OnDestroy" with mTimer.cancel() if you want it to stop ?

Answer (score 1):

This method works when you enter the activity which actually queries the server. Call the method in onCreate. If value returned is true, then fetch data from server, if false, do whatever is in youf flow.

This Example below uses Singleton class. The current system time, plus five minutes is stored in singleton class variable, while local variable stores the current time. If current time exceeds the time of Singleton variable, then true is returned and it is time to call server.

```
SingletonClass app;
app = (SingletonClass ) getApplication();

public boolean serverQueryFrequency() {
        boolean isTimeElapsed;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        // If No Time is set, only then Set the Current time + 10 into
        // application variable. This should fire only once, until 10 minutes
        // have passed
        if (app.getServerCallTime() == 0) {
            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            // updating calendar to get current time + 10
            cal2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);

            long timeTen = cal2.getTimeInMillis();
            app.setServerCallTime(timeTen);

            // returning true, to enable server check
            return true;
        }

        // Log.v("******", "Current :  " + time);
        // Log.v("******", "App Time : " + app.getServerCallTime());

        // Comparing current time with SeverCalltime which is set 10 minutes
        // ahead. Code below fires conditionally as stated
        if (time == app.getServerCallTime() || time > app.getServerCallTime()) {

            isTimeElapsed = true;
            // Once true fired from here, reset serverCallTime
            app.setServerCallTime(0);

        } else {
            // 5 minutes have not passed
            isTimeElapsed = false;
        }

        // returning the related value
        return isTimeElapsed;

    }
```

Comment: that's not what i am looking for

Comment: I re-read your question. You want service to stop when app is closed. Apps aren't totally closed when you exit from it. You've used service, of which the main function is to run in background, when your app isn't visible.

Comment: Yes I want service and its method/thread(that send call and receives data after a time interval) to run in every activity of my app. But I want service to stop when app completely exited from the application. But I dont know where to put this line stopService(new Intent(this, MessagesLoaderService.class)); do i need to add this line in onDestroy() method of main activity? Or need a way to find out when app exit

Comment: If you have a specific flow, where you're sure that when you press back from that activity, app will be closed, that's where you put stop service.

Comment: ok i have got it thanks. But you code above is not relevent. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can stop service by using this line

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MessagesLoaderService.class));
```

so your service get stopped

you need to identify in your app from where your exiting the app at that point you need to call above code also OS automatically kill the service in certain circumstances like low battery and so on but this is not good solution so you can stop it by above line in your exit point of application

Comment: exit point means the point from you are doing exit from your application like exit button on dashboard page or close button from mainpage like this u need to stop it before that code

Answer (score 0):

I have learned when the app is closed the service get closed also because they are in a one thread, so the service should be on another thread in order fot it not to be closed, look into that and look into keeping the service alive with alarm manager here an example http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html this way your service won't be shown in notification.

lastly, after all the research I've done I'm coming to realize that the best use of a long running service is start foreground(); because it is made for that and the system actually deals with your service well.

Answer (score 0):

when the user presses back button on the first page of your app..means they want out.
override the onbackpressed and put the stopService call there.
else..
use an exit button..give it an onclick and inside it put the stopService there